# What is the meaning of measure valued inital condition for a PDE?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, partial-differential-equations

For the following lets consider the heat equation
$$ \begin{cases} u_t -\frac{1}{2}u_{xx}=f(t,x) & t>0 \;\; x \in \mathbb R
\newline u(0,\cdot)=\mu(\cdot) \end{cases} $$
where $\mu$ is a measure on $\mathbb R$ usually satisfying some condition that isn't to important for this question. But for reference, one condition I have seen is that that $\mu$ satisfy $$ \int_{\mathbb R}e^{-ax^2}|\mu|(dx) < \infty \qquad \text{for all $a$>0} $$

My question is what does it mean to have a measure be the inital condition? If $\mu(\cdot)=\delta_0(\cdot)$ then I understand this to mean that initally there is a point mass at $0$. But what if $\mu$ was a different measure, for example Lebesgue measure? What would the initial condition mean in this case?

Also how does this differ from have a function be the initial condition? Is it more general to have a measure initial value and having a function as an initial value is just a specific case of a measure valued initial condition or are the two not related?

Comment: With every PDE must come a definition of solution. Sometimes it is hidden, or assumed as "well-known", but it must be somewhere. Unlike the case of ordinary differential equations, the simple writing of a differential relation is NOT enough. Thus, you should check what the paper you are reading means.

Answer (score 1):

I think that there are two answers to this question:

First: because we can. We know how to deal with initial conditions in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, we know how to deal with $\delta(\cdot)$ so the response of a mathematician would be: can we write this in one general framework? This is possible by lifting your whole problem from "normal" function spaces to distribution spaces and ask all the important questions, like `for what kind of distributions is this equation well defined?'

Second: There are really applications for these kind of things. A short search in my memory resulted in this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.05730.pdf. In the introduction a lot of references are named so you could use this find some examples. Otherwise, you could have a look at [this conference](https://www.lorentzcenter.nl/mathematical-modeling-with-measures-where-applications-probability-and-determinism-meet.html) and google the speakers to find more examples

Comment: I updated the link, but most details on the speakers and subjects seem to have disappeared.